# Is the Logstash "agent" command-line argument necessary? Deprecated?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

In Logstash, does the `agent` command-line argument do anything? Is it deprecated?
I don't find much documentation about it and adding or removing doesn't seem to make a difference in the (simple) cases I've tested.

Answer (score 1):

I think this argument does nothing, because it is not anymore in the 
[documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/command-line-flags.html)

Answer (score 1):

Running the latest Logstash version, I see this:

```
Usage: logstash <command> [command args]
Run a command with the --help flag to see the arguments.
For example: logstash agent --help

Available commands:
  agent - runs the logstash agent
  version - emits version info about this logstash
```

So `agent` is still a valid argument. Since it is actually the only run mode available, it's been made optional and it is always implied.